# Stochastic equivalence of a deterministic perturbation problem

Tags: real-analysis, permutations, expected-value, stochastic-analysis

**Deterministic statement:**

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a scalar-valued continuous function, $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector-valued continuous function, and $\mathcal{N}=\{\mathbb{R}^n \mid \|x-x^*\|^2<\delta\}$ such that
$$
f(y) \leq f(x) - m
$$
where $m>0$ depends on $x^*$ and $y=x+h(x)$.

**Question:**

How can one write the equivalence of the above statement in a stochastic sense?

I think in the above statement what makes it possible is that $h(x)$ does not perturb $x$ that much so I can assume some standard assumptions. What I am not sure about it is how to handle $f(\hat{y})$ where $y=x+\hat{h}(x)$.

**Stochastic statement:**

Now, suppose $\hat{h}(x)$ is a random vector which is an estimation of $h(x)$ such that $h(x)=\mathbb{E}[\hat{h}(x)]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\|h(x)-\hat{h}(x)\|^2]< \sigma^2$.

**Question:**

Under what condition one can write

$$
\mathbb{E}[f(\hat{y})] \leq f(x) - m'
$$

$m'>0$.

Comment: is $h(x)$ meant to be $g(x)$?

Comment: @oliverjones: my bad. I revised it.